# How to parse many div's using Simple HTML DOM?

Tags: dom

I have this HTML code

```
<div id="first" class="first">
    One
    <div id="second" class="second">
        Second
        <div id="third" class="third">
            Third
            <div id="fourth" class="fourth">
                Fourth
                <div id="fifth" clas="fifth">
                   Fifht
                   <div id="sixth" class="sixth">
                       Sixth
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code is from an external website. 
I want to display 'Hi' using Simple HTML DOM from a URL.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to see something like this?

```
$el = $html->find("#first", 0);
while ($child = $el->children(1)) {
    $el = $child;
}
echo $el->innertext;
```

Comment: please, look at my new edit. my first OP was wrong. Now it's like I want. So taking your code, the NEW answer would be with children(6) ??¿?¿ Thanks